# Can MapsterMapper/Mapster map an Expression tree just like AutoMapper do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, object-object-mapping, mapster

MapsterMapper/Mapster 7.3.0

EFCore 7.0.5

asp.net core 7.0.0

I have two generic type in my BuzService class, one is `TModel` and other one is `TEntity`.
`TModel` is a DTO class, `TEntity` is an entity class.

I have a method in the service class

```cs
public virtual async Task<int> UpdateAsync(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> whereLambda,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TModel>> modelFac)
{
    //using Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore extension method, T is an Entity class type.
    //public static Task<int> UpdateAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
    //                                    Expression<Func<T,T>>  updateFactory,
    //                                   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))

    return await DbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable()
            .Where(whereLambda.Adapt<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>())
            .UpdateAsync(modelFac.Adapt<Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>>>());
}
```

`whereLambda.Adapt<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` will throw a `Mapster.CompileException` with a message `Cannot convert immutable type, please consider using 'MapWith' method to create mapping`.

Can Mapster map `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` and `Expression<Func<TModel, TModel>>` to `Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>>`? How to do it?

The code below shows how AutoMapper do this using AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping

```cs
var entityWhere = Mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>(whereLambda);
var entityFac = Mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>>>(modelFac);
return await Repository.UpdateAsync(entityWhere, entityFac);
```